# d3.js make object .enter() timeline at click position and then transition to date

Tags: javascript, arrays, animation, d3.js

I have a d3.js timeline where items are combined if the dates are x number of days apart.

[image]

When you double click the combined items, the timeline zooms and the items are expanded.

[image]

This is done by adding the new items to the timeline array.

My question is about transitions: currently, I am adding a transition on .enter() `transition.duration(1500).ease(d3.easeCubic);`

**I want the animation to look like the newly added items are expanded out of the 'combined' item when you click it.** Currently, they are popping into the timeline at their respective dates which makes it look like they are sliding in from the left.

Is this possible to do? I haven't been able to find much on this.

Comment: How are you setting their positions? Are you using SVGs?

Comment: Yes SVG, and their positions are being set by date. So essentially, I want them to start at the date of the combined item and then transition to their actual date.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code so I can update the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Before you transition the new items set their position to the old item.

```
 // const clickedItem
 const itemsEnter = selection.enter();

 itemsEnter
     // before you create the transition, set their position to the clicked item
     .attr("transform", clickedItem.attr("transform"))
   .transition()
     .duration(1500)
     .ease(d3.easeCubic)
     .attr("transform", (d) => `translate(${d.x}, ${d.y})`);
```

The reason why the transition looks like they are sliding in from the left is because the transition doesn't have starting a point for items that enter. So by default the items that enter will start at the origin (0,0) which is the left side of your slider.